# AST Bravo MS 5166 does not start and signals POST Error

Tags: bios

I'm trying to help a friend fix an old AST Bravo MS 5166 that doesn't want to start. When the computer is powered on, the screen stays black, and the POST beep code goes like this:

```
3 short - 3 long - 7 short
```

As it is quite an old machine, and the manufacturer is no longer active, I'm having a hard time finding any information about both the machine and the errors codes.

According to [this site](http://developer.novell.com/yes/34071.htm), the machine should have BIOS: AST BIOS Rel. 1.00.25

I've tried to Google for those beep codes, but so far I haven't found any useful information. The closest I've got is [this page](http://www.technick.net/public/code/cp_dpage.php?aiocp_dp=guide_beep_codes#AST_PH), that says that 3 short followed by 3 long beeps is `Failure in system board component`.

That doesn't give me much to work with. Are the last 7 short beeps a more specific error message on the system board component error?

Any input on this, about what the error could be, useful resources on beep codes, what I could try, and so forth, would be very much appreciated.